# scrapy installation error on pip install scrapy in python 3.8 version?

Tags: scrapy, python-3.8

`**pip install scrapy**`

```
     command: /home/teamspirit/scrapy-venv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4pcd3gg1/twisted/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4pcd3gg1/twisted/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-8tqiq3oe
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4pcd3gg1/twisted/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4pcd3gg1/twisted/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        exec(f.read(), _setup)
      File "<string>", line 45, in <module>
      File "/home/teamspirit/scrapy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "/home/teamspirit/scrapy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Distribution' from 'pkg_resources' (unknown location)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

while i am try to install scrapy in ubuntu system using vertual environment using pip but i can't install directly ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, and the only online reference I have found to a similar issue is https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1889080

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while installing [enDI app](https://framagit.org/endi/endi/) and running `python setup.py install`.

**First solution** – I rolled back `setuptools` to a previous version than 56.0.0 (eg. 44.0.0) and it worked:

```
$ pip uninstall setuptools
$ pip install setuptools==44.0.0
```

**Second solution** – Recreate the virtual env:

```
$ rmvirtualenv ENV_NAME
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 ENV_NAME
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```